# How to understand "query"?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

The default limit of an account is 1_000_000 queries per day. How should I understand it? Is 1 query = 1 http request (I don't use Batch API).

Comment: No a request can have multiple queries. One query is `?q=one`...

Comment: Be noted that a set of `n` requests [batched](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch#details) together counts toward your usage limit as `n` requests, not as one request. The batch request is taken apart into a set of requests before processing. Since you are not using batch request, I guess one query is treated as a separate HTTP request. However, unlike other APIs, [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) has different quota calculation. All API requests, including invalid requests, incur a quota cost of at least one point.